# How does Facebook Emitter work?

Tags: javascript

How does Facebook Emitter work? i.e. Which code (in the github repo) triggers the `. addListener()`.

https://github.com/facebook/emitter

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. `emit()` **is** the trigger.

Comment: OK, I reworded the question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is just an event pub/sub structure to use in any application.

Nothing really *that* special that I can se..